# re2c: syntax error when trying to match string

Tags: re2c

I'm trying to use re2c, but it gives me a syntax error on this regex:

```
(["'])((\\{2})*|(.*?[^\\](\\{2})*))\1
```

What's wrong with it? This should match a doubly quoted or single quoted string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re2c, like most scanner generators, only implements regular expression primitives which can be implemented in linear time without backtracking. As a consequence, it does *not* implement back-references, captures (although you can insert tag markers into the regular expression) or non-greedy matches. (Technically, non-greedy matches can be implemented in linear time. But it's a bit tricky getting it right.)

The back-reference in your regex is really just an abbreviation, since it can only take on two values: either it is `["]` or `[']`. Separating out the two alternatives also makes it easy to avoid the need for the non-greedy match:

1. If you don't allow newlines in strings:

   ```
   ["]([^"\\\n]|\\.)*["]|[']([^'\\\n]|\\.)*[']
   ```
2. If you allow newlines in strings only if they are escaped:

   ```
   ["]([^"\\\n]|\\(.|\n))*["]|[']([^'\\\n]|\\(.|\n))*[']
   ```
3. If you allow newlines anywhere in strings:

   ```
   ["]([^"\\]|\\(.|\n))*["]|[']([^'\\]|\\(.|\n))*[']
   ```

(Like flex, re2c considers `.` to match any character other than a newline, while negative character classes do include newlines unless specifically mentioned. So newline handling often needs to be explicit.)

Note that re2c does implement quoted literal strings (like flex), so `"` and `'` are metacharacters, a feature which appears in very few regex libraries. (Unlike flex, single-quoted strings are accepted and treated as case-insensitive. In flex, a single quote not a metacharacter.) The consequence is that you must escape them to make them literal characters; the usual convention is to put them inside a character class, as above, rather than using falling timber representation which can be hard to read.

Please read the [documentation for re2c patterns](http://re2c.org/manual/manual.html#regular-expressions), which may have some significant differences to the regex libraries you are used to (or for which you have found examples in a web search).